# Errors when trying to run Sidekiq (Rails 5.2.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

When i am trying to run sidekiq I keep getting this message come up, How would i go about resolving this?

The first time sidekiq was complaining about rack-protect, so i found a fix for that by adding:

```
gem 'sinatra', github: 'sinatra/sinatra' do
                 gem 'rack-protection'
               end
```

When i ran sidekiq again i got the follwoing message

```
Users/r3id/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:313:in `check_for_activated_spec!': 
You have already activated i18n 1.1.0, 
but your Gemfile requires i18n 1.0.1. 
Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

I have tried to update the gemfile, and I have tried running `bundle exec` I am at a total loss. Can any one shed some light on this please?

Running `gem list` shows i have `i18n (1.1.0, 1.0.1)` installed

I even setup a spare Mac with a clean install and rails setup to see if that would fix it, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

So i uninstalled the i18n-1.1.0 gem using `gem uninstall i18n`

When i ran sidekiq this time I was able to run fine.